# Running HHVM in Alpine linux

Tags: php, hhvm, alpine-linux, proxygen

I've been trying to install HHVM (Hack) on Alpine linux to no success.
Has anyone compiled HHVM on linux?

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, there's no HHVM on Alpine yet.

There's an open request in the bug tracker, though:

http://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/4503

maybe you did this request :)

You can monitor the website to see if there are update, or check possibile pull requests from here:

https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pulls

Hope it helps.

Francesco

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this page [Building HHVM from source](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/building-from-source), it requires "GCC 5 or GCC 7". The first step would have to be `apk add --update build-base' or have a look here: [How to get regular stuff working](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_get_regular_stuff_working). buid-base contains "GCC, libc-dev and binutils packages" etc.

Comment: Dockerfile to get you going, got stuck and left it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base git cmake patch curl-dev findutils libxml2-dev icu-dev bash libevent libevent-dev curl
RUN git clone git://github.com/facebook/hhvm.git
RUN cd hhvm
WORKDIR hhvm
RUN git submodule update --init --recursive

ENV GYP_DEFINES "linux_use_bundled_binutils=0 linux_use_bundled_gold=0 clang=0"
RUN cmake -DMYSQL_UNIX_SOCK_ADDR=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock .
RUN make -j [number_of_processor_cores] # eg. make -j 4
RUN make install
```

Got stuck here:
-- Can't find minimal tcmalloc
ERROR: Unable to find Intel TBB install directory.
CMake Error at CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:266 (if):
  if given arguments:

```
"LESS" "5005"
```

Unknown arguments specified
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:106 (include)

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBGLOG_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /hhvm
   used as include directory in directory /hhvm

Would get you going at least halfway.

Think the issue is around :https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/libtbb